# How to edit startup applications?

Tags: startup, settings

If I go to Settings, Applications, Startup, all I see is:

[image]

I remember I had added a few startup scripts (conky etc) and applications (xbindkeys) but I cannot see them there.

I think they were added with a different tool or something.

Comment: Yeah, the `Edit` is a major feature lacking in elementary's 'Startup'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### In Freya

The tool I used is `gnome-session-properties` (of the `gnome-session-bin` package, installed by default)

To launch it I had created a desktop file like so:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/startup.desktop
```

With

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=StartupApps
Comment=View apps starting with the system
GenericName=Startup Applications
Icon=preferences-system
Terminal=false
Categories=Gnome;Gtk;System;
Exec=gnome-session-properties
```

It shows:

[image]

It has edit option.

But it seems that for security reasons in Freya stable the default startup options which were accessible in Freya beta with this tool (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXkjl.png), from [this older answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184752/32012) (that I had forgotten about!)) are now hidden, and only the new custom options are visible.

---

### In Loki

In Loki ' Settings, Applications, Startup' shows the same items as  `gnome-session-properties`.

[image]

But the latter still has the advantage of providing an option to edit the entries (in the former one has to remove and add again an entry in order to modify it).

A cool feature in both  tools is **the possibility to use drag&drop of application launcher files** (the kind of `.desktop` files found in the `applications` folders) onto the window in order to add new startup items. Only such files can be added in this way, not scripts; in order to add scripts, you have to use the 'Add' option.

Comment: Are you using Luna? `gnome-session-properties` does not seem to be available in Freya.

Comment: I tried installing it in Freya too with `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-properties` but it tells me that the package isn't available. You installed this in Freya without adding a PPA?

Comment: @Gabriel - updated: it's `gnome-session-bin` (http://askubuntu.com/a/502764/47206)

Comment: Yep, they are all enabled. Do you remember how you installed that app? Also, `gnome-session-bin` is already installed in Freya by default apparently.

Comment: @Gabriel - look at the askubuntu link: if `gnome-session-bin` is installed, `gnome-session-properties` is too: `/usr/bin/gnome-session-properties`

Comment: Not necessarily, read the comments. There's apparently a bug were that package can be installed but `gnome-session-properties` not. Still not sure how that explains that you have it and I don't. Are you using the official release of Freya or did you install a beta version and simply upgraded?

Comment: @Gabriel - I have installed my system from a live iso that I was able to test right now and can confirm that in a live session of Freya stable (elementaryos-freya-amd64.20150411.iso) the file `gnome-session-properties` is present in `/usr/share` and working.

Comment: Indeed, it is installed and simply launching it from terminal works. It's odd that the system is not recognizing it as installed or even installable, I'm sure it has something to do with the bug I mentioned above. Thank you for helping me debug this!